# Forming a SQL query to compare results across rows

Tags: oracle

Problem statement:

> select all stores name , their status, phone numbers , effective date
>   whose phone number has been changed from 2003 until present date.

Schema is

```
store_name,phone number , start_date , status
```

sample rows

```
    abc 1234  30-DEC-2011 open 
    abc 3433  04-Jan-2012 close
    bbb 4444  30-Jan-2010 open
    bbb 4444  31-Jan-2011 open
```

Output

```
    abc 1234 open 30-DEC-3011 till 3-Jan-2012
    abc 3433 close 04-Jan-2012 till date
```

I am also fine having two rows in output with sorted start date like

```
abc 1234 30-DEC-2011 open
abc  3433 04-Jan-2012 close
```

`bbb` should not be reported as there was no change in phone number. We should report only those stores for which phone number was changed .

Can someone help me with this query on Oracle?  I guess by using correlated queries it can be done but I am not sure how can I construct one.

Please note that my table is having around 3154953 records so I also need to make sure that correlated query doesn't lock the table for whole lot of time.  Is this even possible with Oracle ?

Thanks!

---

APC's answer works for me just that I am seeing alot of repetitions in my result.

For input  :

```
select store_name,phone_number,start_date, status where store_name=abc;
```

returns

```
STORE_name         Phone number start_date     STATUS
---------------- ---------------- ----------- ----------
abc              122 18-JAN-2011          open
abc              122 18-JAN-2011          open
abc              122 18-JAN-2011          close
```

running your query gives me following output.

```
abc              122 open from 18-JAN-2011 to 17-JAN-2011
abc              122 open from 18-JAN-2011 to 17-JAN-2011
abc              122 close  from 18-JAN-2011 to date
```

Can you explain why and where is the miss?

Comment: @ManseUK - you have deleted the [mysql] tag and ignored the reference to MySQL in the title.  Please be certain that your changes will not distort the OP's intentions before you start to edit.

Comment: @APC apologies ... thats 2 editing mistakes ive made today .... added tag back in ... although I really have no idea why its in the title or tagged ?

Comment: @TopCoder - "I am seeing alot of repetitions ... Can you explain why".  Your data contains a lot of repetition.  It's hardly surprising that  duplicated input produces duplicated output, now is it?  As for the the weirdness with the END_DATE, well my query expects there to be a day's grace between records.  If you really have such wacky business logic, well you'll have to tailor the query to cope with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming that this is for Oracle rather than MySQL, as my solution uses a couple of magic tricks which I'm pretty certain are not available in MySQL.  The first is the Common Table Expression to get a result set which we can use more than once.  The second is the use of the LEAD() analytic function to "predict" values in the next row.

So, here's the query:

```
with a as   ( select store_name
             , phone_number
             , status
             , start_date
             , lead (start_date, 1, trunc(sysdate)) over (partition by store_name
                                       order by start_date) as next_date
             , lead (phone_number, 1, null) over (partition by store_name
                                       order by start_date) as next_number
       from your_table 
       where start_date >= date '2003-01-01' ) 
select  a.store_name
      , a.phone_number
      , case  when a.next_date != trunc(sysdate) then 
                  a.status||' from '|| a.start_date ||' to '||to_char(a.next_date - 1)
               else a.status||' from '||a.start_date ||' to date'
              end  as status_text
from a
where a.store_name in (
                select store_name
                from a 
                where phone_number != next_number)
order by a.store_name, a.start_date
/
```

And here's its output:

```
SQL> r
  1  with a as   ( select store_name
...
 22  order by a.store_name, a.start_date                
 23  /

STORE_NAME           PHONE_NUMBER STATUS_TEXT
-------------------- ------------ --------------------------------
abc                          1234 open from 30-DEC-11 to 03-JAN-12
abc                          3433 close from 04-JAN-12 to date

2 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As for this remark:

> "so I also need to make sure that correlated query doesn't lock the
>   table for whole lot of time"

Doesn't matter in Oracle, because reads don't block other reads. Nor writes come to that.

Comment: Thanks! it works great. I also got a chance to read about lead function.

Comment: I am seeing some issues with the result. I edited the question , can you please look into it and let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something along the lines of

```
select * from table0 as q0 join
(
    select min(date) from table0 as q1 where q1.store_name = q0.store_name
) as q2 on q2.store_name = q0.store_name
left join
(
    select max(date) from table0 as q1 where q1.store_name = q0.store_name
) as q3 on q3.store_name = q0.store_name
```

That's not quite right as I don't have MySQL in front of me but its something along these lines.